# It is possible to control the volume of left/right channel with Youtube Android V3 API?

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

Currently I fail to control the volume of right/left channel with Youtube Android V3 API.I found there are some examples about `SoundPool` or `MediaPlayer`. But I still found no hint to work this with Youtube Android API after reading all it's documents. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, no. I am not aware of any plans to add that functionality into any of the Player APIs.